# Read SMBIOS of a remote PC

Tags: c, linux, ethernet, bios

I know that when a PC is OFF, some components still working ,like the motherboard, the NIC (network card), and others. I thought that like the 'magic packet' send to the NIC on the *Wake-on-Lan* do, there is a form of sending another signal to this one.

**How can I get the SMBIOS table, through the Network Card of a remote and power-off PC?**

If someone knows of some code example, or manual which can read to learn, it would be very helpful.

Comment: The cards are listening as long as they're powered, however the only functionality I'm aware of is "Wake On LAN", which requires that you send a special packet containing the MAC address, and there is no reply. It just turns on the computer.

Comment: where can I find Info about the signals that the NIC listen?

Comment: AFAIK, There's only one: WOL. 

There are docs all over the net. You can start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Magic_packet

Comment: Have a look at Intel ME. It's very proprietary and largely undocumented though.

Comment: I need something more compatible with others processors architectures, like AMD...

Comment: @Shanks There is nothing "more compatible". A machine that's off is off. You can turn the machine on if the card supports it, and this is not dependent on the processor, but at that point, all you've done is turned on the machine.

Comment: @Shanks IME is available during "sleep" but not "off" and it's specific to Intel. You're looking for something that doesn't exist. There are no commands that will do anything to a powered off computer except turn it on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get the SMBIOS table, through the Network Card of a remote and power-off PC?

You can't. WoL is a function of the NIC. When it receives a magic packet it triggers a PMI event, waking up the mainboard - that's it. You can't magically talk through the NIC to the powered down system.

There are two solutions, depending on your actual goal:

1. Many servers, some workstations and PCs feature lights-out management through a baseboard management controller - features differ, you'll need to select the appropriate product.
2. Wake the machine, run whatever queries you need and shut it down again. This is a standard procedure for client management.

Comment: I'll take the second one.

Comment: IIUIC, you can talk to a powered-down system through a NIC and Intel AMT and get some BIOS information...

Comment: @radekholy24 AMT is a kind of lights-out management that I referred to above.